# Conversion tracking in google analytics with GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have recently installed Google Tag manager on a Magento webshop, and added my analytics code to a tag, and my Adwords Conversion info to another tag.

Sales are now being tracked fine in Google Adwords, but doesn't show up in Google Analytics as sales. I have enabled Ecommerce in Google analytics, and before using GTM it worked fine. Both my Adwords account and my Analytics account are linked. Visitors are tracked just fine, just not sales in analytics.

So what do I also need to setup in order to see my sales in analytics from the various sources?

Comment: Are you able to share a screenshot of your tag setup for capturing the transaction? Are you capturing it as part of the pageview and clicking "Enabled Enhanced Ecommerce" in the tag?